# in node.js, SQL command not properly ended at Error(native)

Tags: node.js, oracle

I'm using oracle in node.js, and I want to insert my sql query.

I tried to insert my query, but i can't insert.

This is my error:

```
Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

This is my SQL query.

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('P0315','hey');
```

So, I tried it in sqlplus directly, and result is

```
1 row created.
```

Only in node.js, I find error.
I use npm oracledb, and this is my insert code.

```
    var sql = "INSERT INTO test VALUES ('P0315','hey');";
    var doinsert1 = function (conn, cb) {
    console.log(sql);
    conn.execute(
        sql,
        function(err, result)
        {
            if (err) {
                return cb(err, conn);
            } else {
                console.log("Rows inserted: " + result.rowsAffected);  // 1
                return cb(null, conn);
            }
        });
};
```

can I ask why it doesn't work in only node.js?

Comment: I don't use node, and it's not the error I'd expect to see generally, but what happens if you remove the semicolon at the end of your query (inside the double-quotes)?

Comment: I think @AlexPoole is correct, I just checked the npm doc for oracledb at https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#sqlexecution, there is no semicolon at the end.

Comment: oh, thank you for your help! I get another problem, but I can solve that problem! I don't know that semicolon makes that error! :O I really appreciate your help! :D

Comment: Thanks so much. I have been looking for the solution since last 2 centuries.

Answer (score 3):

Syntax in `npm oracledb` should not have a semi-colon in the SQL statement